# A particular use of the expression "turn down"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I have just come upon the following sentence in a book:

> "A page was turned down, as if to draw attention to some passage".
>
> (The specific context is very simple: the character has taken a book and started reading it.)

As a non-native speaker, I am quite intrigued by the use of the expression "turn down" in this case. None of the [Lexico definitions](https://www.lexico.com/definition/turn_down) fits. Does it mean the page was "marked" by the reader somehow? Is it common to use "turn down" this way?

Comment: Some people have a habit of folding (turning) down the *corner* of a page instead of using a bookmark.

Comment: Thank you, Weather Vane!

Comment: @WeatherVane Yes, it's also called **dog-earing** because the turned down corner looks like a dog's ear. Doing this to a cheap novel you've taken on holiday is neither here nor there, doing it to a book you're going to keep, or even worse one you've borrowed, is tantemount to vandalism.